# socket timeout after an hour

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

So I am polling data every 60s and after about an hour I get this error.
Not too sure what this is or how to avoid it. I know I am definitely over-polling, since the API faq said it could handle 40 requests per second.

This is the code I am using:

```
def httpPost(url,resource,params):
 headers = {
        "Content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
 }
 conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(url, timeout=10)
 temp_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
 conn.request("POST", resource, temp_params, headers)
 response = conn.getresponse()
 data = response.read().decode('utf-8')
 params.clear()
 conn.close()
 return data
```

And the trace back:

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1172, in getresponse response.begin()
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 351, in begin version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 313, in _read_status
 line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 371, in readinto
 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 746, in recv_into
return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 618, in read
 v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
```

Hopefully someone has dealt with this issue before or can help me understand it.

Would I need to add a timeout exception to the code?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: You might like to log the server's behaviour, as if it's not the network, then it's the server does doesn't "answer" anymore.

Comment: how do i log the server's behavior?

Comment: Have you tried polling another server, and see if the same behaviour occurs?

Comment: Yes, this same occurrence happened when I polled a different server